# How to find out T1H, T1L, T0H and T0L for ledstrip WS2813?

Tags: led-strip, timing

I have bought a led strip WS2813 from AliExpress. It does not have a decent datasheet with all details, neither does the seller knows about.

I tried different settings (for what I could find at some datasheets for WS2813), but none seem to work.

Than I tried to use 4 potentiometers which I used to vary the 4 times (T1H..T0L). However, I couldn't get e.g. a full red or green light. Probably the timing is incorrect.

Is there an 'easy' way to find out these times?

I used 'nop' assembly statements for delay, but when using the potentiometers I used a for loop which gives about a 50 ns minimum delay/accuracy, which should be ok.

Comment: You might check out the code in the Arduino library FastLED. Even if you're not using Arduino to control the LEDs, it should shed some light on the timing. I've used FastLED for Arduino and other readily available libraries for Raspberry Pi and never had a problem.

Comment: Thanks, at least I can check the timing indeed from that library.

Comment: For those playing at home:
www.normandled.com/upload/201605/WS2813%20LED%20Datasheet.pdf

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen I already checked this one, and some others, there are some differences in values for T1/T0 values between different data sheets.

Comment: You should try to identify the manufacturer of the actual LED devices and get the datasheet from them.